# How to get Number Of Lines without Reading File To End

Tags: c#, algorithm, text

Is there a way to get Number of Lines within a Large Text file ,but without Reading the File content or reading file to end and Counting++.

Maybe there are some File Attributes ,but cannot find it out at all .
Because i might be in some cases where i should get Total Number of Line's and compare it to Current line to display the Percentage,and just for a Percentage Display it might be stupid to read first all Content than read it Again to Display the raw text at user.

bests

Comment: If you control the file format, you could inject the number of lines as some meta data either in an external file or in the header of the file. You could also read through, character-by-character and check for newline characters. That would not be terribly fast though.

Comment: Much as everyone has already stated, a viable option would be to add your own header to the file. I did this for a custom Wavefront model implementation for my game. Basically, I have a tool that optimizes .obj files, getting rid of crap I don't need, and then writes the total number of lines, faces, normals, vertices, and texture UVs on the very first line. That data is then used by various array buffers when the model is loaded.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

No. You have to read the file. Consider storing it at the beginning of the file or in a separate file when you write the file if you want to find it quickly without counting.

Note that you can stream the file, and it's surprisingly fast:

```
int count = File.ReadLines(path).Count();
```

> Because i might be in some cases where i should get Total Number of Line's and compare it to Current line to display the Percentage,and just for a Percentage Display it might be stupid to read first all Content than read it Again to Display the raw text at user.

Oh, just get the file size and the length of each line in bytes and keep a cumulative count of the number of bytes processed so far.

Comment: I think that will cause memory trouble ,because i handle with File's < > 8Gb Log File's generated from another Application

Comment: @Cody: The `File.ReadLines` method doesn't read the entire file at once, so it won't use much memory. It's only available in Framework 4 or later, though.

Comment: @Cody: you might want to try that. `File.ReadLines` returns an `IEnumerable<string>` - it does not read the entire file into memory at one time.

Comment: @Cody: No, as I mentioned, it streams the file. It will not read the whole file into memory. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd383503.aspx

Comment: @Jason yeah, the IEnumerable itself wont, but doesnt the .Count() trigger the enumeration to actually execute, therefore reading everything at once?

Comment: @UrbanEsc: No, it still streams the file. It's a loop that basically looks like `int count = 0; using(var e = source.GetEnumerator()) { while(e.MoveNext()) { count++; } } return count;` And `var = source.GetEnumerator()` and `e.MoveNext()` basically opens the file as a `StreamReader` and then repeatedly does a `StreamReader.ReadLine`. There is no buffering of the file.

Comment: @Jason its kind of weird that you copied my answer and got the vote for it. guess lifes unfair, right?

Comment: @UrbanEsc: It's kind of weird that you assumed I copied your answer (I didn't). The idea is kind of obvious. Also, I had the sole vote that I have on my answer before I edited the idea in. (By the way, when the OP first posted the question, that part about why he needed the count wasn't there; he added it in the the edit window and I edited my answer accordingly.)

Comment: @UrbanEsc: Also, reading your answer now, you do not need any voodoo. It's really simple. Read the line. Get the number of bytes in the **encoding**, and accumulate.

Answer (score 13):

No, there is no other way.

A file is not line based (or even character based), so there is no meta information about the number of lines (or even number of characters). The only meta data about the content is the length in bytes.

If you have some additional information about the file, for example that each line is exactly the same length, and it uses an 8-bit encoding so that the number of characters is the same as the number of bytes, you could calculate the number of lines from the file size.

Comment: +1 ...and have a defined line ending sequence, e.g., `\r\n` vs. `\n`

Comment: @Guffa could you tell FileZilla that :P - no just Joking ,im handling with FileZilla Log File's and they're terribly large so i think i will not display the Percentage .

Comment: @Cody: You could use an estimated average line length to get an approximate precentage, or calculate the percentage based on file position instead of line.

Answer (score 5):

As Guffa and Jason said, there is no way to get the lines other than reading to the end.

**To solve your problem differently:**

If you are interested only in the percentage display you COULD try to acummulate that value from the total file size and the line you are currently at. You need to apply some voodoo tricks there to get the actual bytes read (like say, you have read to line 10, and a total of 200 bytes or whatever) and the file size is 400bytes. You could probably guess that you are at 50%, without giving needing to know a total line number.

Thats just some random numbers there, btw.

Comment: If you only need percentage and not the total line number i think its totally doable